# upload file with slackclient 2.x

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm upgrading from `slackclient` `1.3.1` to `2.9.3` using [this guide](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/wiki/Migrating-to-2.x).

before I had this function:

```
     def upload_file(self, file, filename, title, channel):
         return self.slack_client.api_call(
             "files.upload",
             channels=channel,
             filename=filename,
             title=title,
             file=file)
```

which I tried to migrate to:

```
    def upload_file(self, file, filename, title, channel):
    return self.web_client.api_call(
        "files.upload",
        json={'channels': channel,
              'filename': filename,
              'title': title,
              'file': file})
```

the function is called with something like this:

```
with open("/vm-root/app/" + log, 'rb') as f:
    instance.upload_file(f, log, log, channel)
```

However, I get:

> Object of type 'BufferedReader' is not JSON serializable

I am guessing it is related to the way I pass the `file` parameter. How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the parameters were wrong:

```
    def upload_file(self, file, filename, title, channel):
    return self.web_client.api_call(
        "files.upload",
        files={'file': file},
        data={'channels': channel,
              'filename': filename,
              'title': title})
```